# close view after touch android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I've got a Activty which is displayed after a info-button is pressed. Now I want to close/ destroy the activty, when the user touches the screen, so that the user can get back to the main-activty again, without pressing the back-button of the device. How does the code look like.

I tried this, but it has no effect:

```
if(onTouchEvent(null)){
        finish();
}
```

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

This is the whole code I have:

```
public class InfoDialog extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog); }
```

I use this Class just to show a short Information about the App with in the android-style of Theme.Dialog 
 However, I want to add one function, to destroy/ close this activty, when the touchscreen is pressed, so that there is no need to press the back-button.

Comment: what you used, did you make visible of that view or use activity to show the info ?

Comment: There's not enough code to answer your question.

Comment: did you mean that if(onTouchEvent!=null)????

Comment: I use a activty. And I want to destroy the activty after the touchscreen is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutId);

mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
something like that:

```
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
   switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         finish();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to that view which displays your info. And then set a onTouch listener on that view and if use activity then finish the activity or if used visibility then make it invisible.

```
main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                finish();
            }
        }
```

or

```
info = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);

info = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.info);
info.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                info.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```